# Entity Framework : Unable to change DataSource for Code First Migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on a project where I am using Entity Framework along with code first migrations to update my database. I started this project on another machine and it worked out very well. Now I checked out the code on another machine. Since this machine does not have the database, I ran update-database command in nuget. It should apply my previous migrations and create a new database on this machine but it is displaying following error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxpf9.png)

I read [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) article which says

> If a local SQL Express instance is available (installed by default with Visual Studio 2010) then Code First has created the database on that instance
>   If SQL Express isn’t available then Code First will try and use LocalDb (installed by default with Visual Studio 2012)

What I understand by this is when i enabled migrations in my first machine, it created database with SQLEXPRESS instance as DataSource and since I don't have that in my current machine, It is unable to create the database. So I am trying to change the DataSource of EntityFramework to the Instance of my current sql server which is LAPTOP-HD618J49. For this I tried to write a hard coded connection string with this instance in app.config, changed ContextName in Data Context class but to no avail. Please give me some directions on what I might be missing?

Comment: I would suggest you specify a connection string name in the constructor of your context as described [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx). Then add that connection string to your config file. Should be no need to change the name of the context.

Comment: @SteveGreene i tried that as well. Still the same error.

Comment: First thing to do is use SQL Server Object explorer in VS (or SQL Management Studio) to connect to the desired database and insure you have access (you won't have access to remote database by default). Second, does your error message still refer to '.\SQLEXPRESS'? That indicates it is not using your connection string for LAPTOP-HD618J49.

Comment: did you try `: base("name=connectionstringname")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue. Earlier I tried to use `base("name=ConnectionStringNameHere")` but it didn't worked when I ran update-database command in package manager console. The strange reason is Visual Studio don't know which app.config to check for ConnectionStringName. Although I had already selected the module with entity framework in the dropdown of package manager console. I had to select the module with entity framework from the solution explorer window and set it as startup project. This somehow solved the problem and It was able to pick ConnectionStringName from app.config of the module with the updated DataSource.